# how to read a specific key or row from a json file and send the value to the server side

Tags: java, angularjs, html, rest

I have a json file like below-

```
    "af": "af-ZA",
    "ar": "ar",
    "bg": "bg-BG",
    "ca": "ca-AD",
    "cs": "cs-CZ",
    "cy": "cy-GB",
    "da": "da-DK",
    "de": "de-DE",
    "el": "el-GR",
    "en": "en-US",
    "es": "es-ES",
    "et": "et-EE",
    "eu": "eu",
    "fa": "fa-IR",
    "fi": "fi-FI",
    "fr": "fr-FR",
    "he": "he-IL",
    "hr": "hr-HR",
    "hu": "hu-HU",
    "id": "id-ID",
    "is": "is-IS",
    "it": "it-IT",
    "ja": "ja-JP",
    "km": "km-KH",
    "ko": "ko-KR",
    "lt": "lt-LT",
    "lv": "lv-LV",
    "mn": "mn-MN",
    "nb": "nb-NO",
    "nl": "nl-NL",
    "nn": "nn-NO",
    "pl": "pl-PL",
    "pt": "pt-PT",
    "ro": "ro-RO",
    "ru": "ru-RU",
    "sk": "sk-SK",
    "sl": "sl-SI",
    "sr": "sr-RS",
    "sv": "sv-SE",
    "th": "th-TH",
    "tr": "tr-TR",
    "uk": "uk-UA",
    "vi": "vi-VN",
    "zh": "zh-CN"
```

from where i want to read few rows using angular js controller and the value i want to send to the server side which java rest based controller.

And is it possible to send different language to the server side. like - French , chines, Arabic etc.

how can i achieve above features?

Comment: I want.. I want.. what's your question?

Comment: May be this will help you [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) and then just take needed property from deserialized object.

Answer (score 0):

You can send whatever name/value pairs to the server you deem necessary.  How your server code interprets those name/value pairs and manipulates the session and/or response based on those values is application-specific.

For example, some web frameworks like Struts allow you to make a web request and append a specific named parameter, `request_locale` with a correctly formatted language key and it will automatically adjust the locale and the response will be based on the specified locale.

Comment: my first question is how to filter specific key from json file using angularjs controller.